# DB2 Update query with select statement

Tags: db2

I have a table named 'DATA' which looks like below

[DATA TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XuUn.png)

My requirement is to mask the records with duplicate APP_HLD_CD values i.e., I need to first identify all the APP_NBRs with duplicate APP_HLD_CD and then change the value of CITY.

In the example table DATA, the APP_NBR = 12345 has 4 records with duplicate values for APP_HLD_CD as 5 and 77 and like wise APP_NBR = 63746 has duplicate values 5 and 90.

I am dealing with millions of records unlike the example stated above so I am not looking at a simple UPDATE query here. I need to identify the APP_NBRs with duplicate records so I came up with this query to do that

```
SELECT CITY, APP_NBR, APP_HLD_CD, COUNT(APP_HLD_CD) FROM DATA
GROUP BY CITY, APP_NBR, APP_HLD_CD
HAVING COUNT(APP_HLD_CD) > 1;
```

Now in order to update the CITY of all the APP_NBR records having duplicate APP_HLD_CD values I came up with the below query

```
UPDATE DATA
SET CITY = '***'
WHERE (CITY, APP_NBR, APP_HLD_CD) IN 
(
 SELECT CITY, APP_NBR, APP_HLD_CD, COUNT(APP_HLD_CD) FROM DATA
 GROUP BY CITY, APP_NBR, APP_HLD_CD
 HAVING COUNT(APP_HLD_CD) > 1
);
```

Can someone help me with tweaking this query to achieve the result that I am expecting

Comment: Please, don't post pictures. If someone would like to help you with some example query, there is no fun to type all the corresponding data from such a picture. What's the problem with this "simple UPDATE query"? Do you get unexpected result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.